# How to programmatically set the github repo inside jenkins job configuration page

Tags: python, github, jenkins, docker

I want to set the Github repository url in http://host-ip:8080/job/my_project/configure jenkins page via code each time I spawn a new Jenkins container.

I read that this can be done with python-jenkins's [reconfig_job function](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.reconfig_job) by replacing the config.xml .

Well how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some clues in "[How can I update a jenkins job using the api?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22498315/6309)"

For instance, since you spawn a new Jenkins container, you can **[`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/)** an updated `config.xml` to the container (at the right path for that job)

(the [OP Kostas Demiris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163667/kostas-demiris) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198318/how-to-programmatically-set-the-github-repo-inside-jenkins-job-configuration-pag/33200000?noredirect=1#comment54236562_33200000) it works, when run in git bash)

You can also use one of the [Jenkins API libraries](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), but check if a [simple curl is enough first](https://benkiew.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/automating-hudsonjenkins-via-rest-and-curl-a-very-small-cookbook/)

```
#Get the current configuration and save it locally
curl -X GET http://user:password@jenkins.server.org/job/myjobname/config.xml -o mylocalconfig.xml

#Update the configuration via posting a local configuration file
curl -X POST http://user:password@jenkins.server.org/job/myjobname/config.xml --data-binary "@mymodifiedlocalconfig.xml"
```

The [updated Jenkins doc mentions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) (for updating just one parameter in an existing config job):

```
Simple example - sending "String Parameters":

curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --data token=TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'

Another example - sending a "File Parameter":

curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --user USER:PASSWORD \
  --form file0=@PATH_TO_FILE \
  --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"FILE_LOCATION_AS_SET_IN_JENKINS", "file":"file0"}]}'
```

Comment: With this command :  curl -X POST http://username:password@host.com:8686/job/MyJob/config.xml --data-binary "@new_config.xml" from the directory of new_config PowerShell throws 'Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X' '

Comment: @KostasDemiris Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.