# Jenkins management via application

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins

Is it possible to execute a jenkins task from an application?

For instance, a user could click on a button in the application and start a jenkins task.

I'm using PHP and laravel framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API):

> Simple example - sending "String Parameters":
>
> `curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
>
>   --data token=TOKEN \
>
>   --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'`

If you are using PHP, then you need to use some HTTP Client. I recommend [GuzzleHTTP](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) which is easy to [integrate](https://medium.com/laravel-5-the-right-way/using-guzzlehttp-with-laravel-1dbea1f633da#.4gmbx9loh) with Laravel.

Comment: Great, it works with Guzzle, thanks!

The purpose of my question is I would like that the user is able to schedule himself a jenkins task by giving some parameters in the URL (day, month, year, hours, minutes).

I tried to use "Build periodically with parameters" in the jenkins task: H * * * * %Parameter1=Parameter1

url: http://myuser:usertoken@localhost:8080/job/myJenkinsTask/buildWithParameters?Parameter1=myParam&token=myToken

As you see, it's not the right way to do that. I would like to replace some * by the parameters sent into the url. 

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @xAngy Ok, so you are trying to edit job's configurations. The answer is there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498315/how-can-i-update-a-jenkins-job-using-the-api

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!